# Is buffer the right way to test that a method echoes something?

Tags: php

Suppose to have a class "Debug" with a "log" function that MUST output exactly the message passed to the function. Is there a good way to test it?

```
class DebugTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        ob_start();

        $d = new Debug;

        $d->log('foo');

        $this->assertEquals(
            'foo',
            ob_get_clean()
        );
    }
}
```

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [best way](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output) (as of 2017) to check the output of the tested code is to use the function [`expectOutputString()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L503):

```
class DebugTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        // Set the expectation
        $this->expectOutputString('foo');

        // Run the tested code
        $d = new Debug;
        $d->log('foo');
    }
}
```

Behind the scene, `expectOutputString()` does the buffering trick for you. 
The method is available since PHPUnit 3.6.0 (that was released more than 5 years ago.)